# IIS Server not serving ASP.Net application

Tags: iis-6

I am getting the following exception on my IIS server:

aspnet_wp.exe could not be started. The error code for the failure is C0000005. This error can be caused when the worker process account has insufficient rights to read the .NET Framework files. Please ensure that the .NET Framework is correctly installed and that the ACLs on the installation directory allow access to the configured account

IIS 6 installed, then .Net 4.0 installed

Does not server up a default web application, does not report anything to the event viewer.

Any ideas how to debug & find the root cause for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Aspnet_regiis.exe to repair IIS mappings for ASP.NET?

Here is a link (specifically for IIS 6) that might help you.
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/187d0e2c-8e89-49ad-a89d-e26e4d76ee68.mspx?mfr=true